# NSFetchRequest not display anything

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to display items in a tableView, but my fetchResult Array does not show anything.
I get this NSLog:

```
2013-09-13 13:02:01.088 Prototype[67018:c07] managed object ()
```

YPProjectListVC.h

```
@interface YPProjectListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

YPProjectListVC.m

```
@interface YPProjectListViewController () {
    SelectionSuccessBlock successBlock;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * data;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *spinner ;
@end

@implementation YPProjectListViewController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize data;
@synthesize spinner;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

Here is my request:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
       spinner = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 10, 40, 40)];
    
    managedObjectContext = [YPDataSingleton context];
    
    if(managedObjectContext){
        
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entity];
        request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]];
        
        NSError *error;
        self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *fetchResults  = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (error != nil) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        data=[fetchResults mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"managed object %@",fetchResults);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        
        
        [self loadProjectsFromService];
        [spinner addTarget:self action:@selector(loadProjectsFromService) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [tableView addSubview:spinner];
        
    }
}
```

Here is where I get my Projects from the services if NSManagedObjectContext is empty.

```
    -(void)loadProjectsFromService{
         [spinner beginRefreshing];
        self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        successBlock = ^(NSDictionary *newData) {
            if ([newData count] > 0) {
                [weakSelf refreshData:newData];
            }
           
        };
            [spinner endRefreshing];
        [ypNetManager getProjectListWithSuccessBlock:successBlock error:NULL];
    
    }
```

## pragma mark - Custom getter

```
- (UITableView *)tableView {
    //custom init of the tableview
    if (!tableView) {
        // regular table view
        tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.view.bounds, tableViewInsets) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        return tableView;
    }
    return tableView;
}

#pragma mark - Private methods 

- (void)refreshData:(NSDictionary *)newData {
 
        
        for (NSDictionary *projectDic in newData) {
          [data addObject:[Project createProjectWithDictionary: projectDic inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
        }
    
    
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    
}
```

Comment: Pass the `error` parameter in the `executeFetchRequest:error:` API call and print the error in case your fetch request is failing. You will get to know the reason.

Comment: it does not get in the error log. It is really weird, fetchResults is not nil... but then it does not show anything

Comment: The `if` condition needs to be changed to check `if(error!=nil)` and then print the `error`.

Comment: I got the same NSlog, I mean error is nil

Comment: maybe try a count on NSLog(@"managed object %i",[fetchResults count]); see if you are getting correct number u expect ? You getting results in other views ?

Comment: `2013-09-13 15:05:53.549 Prototype[68985:c07] managed object 0` this is the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use NSFetchedResultsController, It will to the job for you, feed and update your table view carefully.

Look here:[Core Data Tutorial for iOS: How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

**Edit**

I still think that you should use above but for now, I can understand that you are not implementing  to the delegate and the data source methods of the table view?

Basicly you need to impliment the methods that tells the table view:

**Data source**

The data source is what you need to give to the table view, for example:

1. How many sections it should have
2. How many rows in any section
3. what is the content to add to the table cells

There are more but those are the basic methods.

**Delegate**

WHen you are conforming as the delegate of the table view, you simply give the table view a way to inform you about things like:

1. user tapped the one of the cells
2. user tapped the accessory button
3. user started to edit the table

and so on...

It is long explanation for here tough it is quite simple, and there are a lot of tutorials that will help you.

try looking here:

[Apple example project for tableViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)

And here

[TableView Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

Comment: I will use this in a future. but I would like to solve my problem. Other point is that I have create the tableView programmatically and I dont know how to pass these parameter : `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: I have edited my question. There it is what I use to manage my tableView, without delegate methods and datasource: heightForRowAtIndex...,didSelected...numberOfSection...numberOfRows..cellForRowAtIndexPath.. I have implemented this methods but maybe you do not need to see them.

Comment: If you want to see that methods just tell me. I think that my problem to understand how to use that class of the link that you posted, is that I have an UIViewController and not an UITableViewController

Comment: I have add that classes, I have the files in the link. what do you think? This does not work. I know it is not well implemented but I dont know how. Files [link](https://bitbucket.org/roxeman3/projecttable-files/src)